# Django: template display value from many to many through table

Tags: python, django, django-templates, many-to-many, relationship

I have 3 models and I'm trying to acces and display datas from the "through" table on a many-to-many relation (Django).

I try to display 3 things :

- the artwork image,
- the translation language used
- the translated name of the artwork

I'm failling to do the last one. It it from the "through" link of the many to many relation); any idea ?

**Models.py :**

```
class Language(models.Model):
    LANG = (
        ('FR', 'FR'),
        ('EN', 'EN'),
    )
    lang_selected = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LANG, verbose_name='Availlable language')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lang_selected 

class Artwork(models.Model):
    artwork_image = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name="Artwork image")
    version = models.ManyToManyField(Language, through='Artwork_language', verbose_name="link artwork -> language")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artwork_image

class Artwork_language(models.Model):
    Artwork = models.ForeignKey(Artwork, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    artwork_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name="Artwork name")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Artwork) + " translated to " + str(self.Language)
```

**views.py**

```
class Accueil(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'isa/accueil.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['artwork'] = Artwork.objects.all()
        context['language'] = Language.objects.all()
        context['artwork_language'] = Artwork_language.objects.all()

        return context
```

**Template** (accueil.html)

```
    <h1>Image  | Language translation | Translated name</h1>

{% for artwork in artwork %}
    Image : {{ artwork.artwork_image }} <br/>
        {% for lang in artwork.version.all %}
                Language translation :  {{ lang }}  <br/>
                Translated name :  {{ ### }}
                {% for i in lang.artwork_language %}
                {{ i.artwork_name }}
                {% endfor %}
                <br/>
        {% endfor %}
```

---

### [image: preview]

I tried a lot of thing in the `Translated name :  {{ ### }}` but nothing seem to work; am i totaly on the wrong road ?

Comment: You need to approach this from the other direction. You should follow the relationship to Artwork_language, and then the FK to Language from there. But I actually can't understand from your question what you actually want to display; what is that nested loop for? And your confusion between Language and Version doesn't really help.

Comment: yes, i know, sorry  Daniel Roseman; i changed all my variable name to english for people to understand better and i didnt write any exemple because i thought it wasn't useful for the reader; i tried to make a for loop inside { Artwork_language.artwork_name }; i tried to call context with every possible parameter and nothing seems to work; i have no idea why : {{ lang.artwork_name }}; {{ lang.artwork_language.artwork_name }} and many others possibilities...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you should follow the relationship to Artwork_language, and then the FK to Language from there:

```
{% for artwork_lang in artwork.artwork_language_set.all %}
    Language translation :  {{ artwork_lang.Language }}  <br/>
    Translated name :  {{ artwork_lang.artwork_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to the through model's attributes when you access the related instances vie the many-to-many field's related manager. You could use the default `related_name` of the fk in the through model, however:

```
{% for art_lang in artwork.artwork_language_set.all %}
     Language translation :  {{ art_lang.Language }}  <br/>
     Translated name :  {{ art_lang.artwork_name }}
     {% for i in art_lang.Language.artwork_language_set.all %}
         {{ i.artwork_name }}
     {% endfor %}
     <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
# inventory/models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    purchase_order = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    purchase_items = models.ManyToManyField('Item', through =        'ItemPurchaseOrder')

    def  __str__(self):
        return 'Purchase order:' + str(self.purchase_order)

class ItemPurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchaseorder = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder,     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchase_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)

# inventory/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Item, PurchaseOrder, ItemPurchaseOrder

# Create your views here.
class ItemListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    context_object_name = 'item_list'
    template_name = 'inventory/inventory.html'

class PurchaseOrderListView(ListView):
    model = PurchaseOrder
    context_object_name = 'po_list'
    template_name = 'inventory/po_list.html'

class PurchaseOrderDetailView(DetailView):
    model = PurchaseOrder
    context_object_name = 'po_det_list'
    template_name = 'inventory/po_detail.html'

# inventory/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import ItemListView, PurchaseOrderListView,     PurchaseOrderDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ItemListView.as_view(), name='inventory'),
    path('purchaseorder/', PurchaseOrderListView.as_view(),     name='po_list'),
    path('purchasedetail/<int:pk>/', PurchaseOrderDetailView.as_view(),     name='po_detail')
]

<!-- templates/inventory/po_detail.html -->
{% extends '_base.html' %} 
{% block title %}Purchase Order Detail{% endblock title %} 
{% block content %} 
  {{ po_det_list.pk }}
{% for poli in po_det_list.itempurchaseorder_set.all %} 
  {{ poli.item }} {{ poli.purchase_quantity }}
{% endfor %}
```

{% endblock content %}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).