# Django: display many to many relationship through a model in template

Tags: django, django-models

I have this ManyToMany relationship through an intermediary model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='NamedMembershipClub')

class Membership(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm trying to display members with the year they joined in my template.
I read on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991474/django-template-display-value-from-many-to-many-through-table) that I should use `members_set.all`

```
{% for member in object.members_set.all %}
    <p>{{member.user.first_name}} {{member.year}}</p> 
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't produce any output, the loop is just not entered because the set is empty.
I also tried :

```
{% for member in object.members.all %}
    <p>{{member.first_name}}</p> 
{% endfor %}
```

The view:

```
class DetailGroupView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'group/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.object = Group.object.get(slug=kwargs['slug'])
        context['object'] = self.object
        return context
```

Which gives some satisfaction because I can display the user but not the associated data in the Membership model.
Is there any way to get the set directly in the template ? Thanks!
I'm running Django 3.0.

Comment: Hey, can you post your views?

Comment: Sure I added it in the post.